# Wordpress custom URL htaccess not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having a URL in wordpress which needs to be changed.

`http://www.somedomain.com/site/other-jobs/view/?action=view&title=php-developer&JOB_ID=158`

I want to make this URL to look something like this:

`http://www.somedomain.com/php-developer/158`

I tried putting htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /site/other-jobs/view/?action=view&title=$1&JOB_ID=$2 [L]
```

But this is not working, can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin:

[Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

It allows you to redirect any URL.

It can be useful the [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/) also.

And ensure:

1 `AllowOverride All` is established in the right Directory context.

2 `Options +FollowSymLinks` is added just before `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin, can you help me within the code?